# Relative URLs in Firefox not working when using IP address

Tags: html

I have been learning to code HTML and javascript and have run into a slightly confusing (and very frustrating issue) around loading scripts and css using relative paths when accessing the page using an IP address. Both Chrome 30.0.1599.69 and IE10 seem to have no problem but Firefox 24 does, and only when using an IP address rather than the name.

Folder structure is:

```
Dashboard/index.html
Dashboard/css/dashboard.css
Dashboard/js/dashboard.css
Dashboard/leaflet/
etc
```

The HTML looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- css loading -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dashboard.css" /> 
    <!-- script loading -->
    <script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dashboard.js"></script>
    <script src="d3.v3/d3.v3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     etc...
```

The above works fine when opened via localhost (using python simpleHTTPServer) in all browsers (`http://localhost:8888/Dashboard/` in the browser bar). When I move the Dashboard folder and subfolders to the default webpage area (`C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\`) in Windows Server 2003/IIS 6.0 and attempt to access the page it also works fine - until I try it with the IP address using Firefox.

For example, `http://mywebpage/Dashboard/index.html` brings up the page and loads all the css, js files etc correctly. Using the console I can see:

`[10:57:32.081] GET http://mywebpage/Dashboard/css/dashboard.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 10ms]`

When I try it with an IP (as the name only resolves on our network and I want to display the page when outside) I get the following error in Firefox:

`[10:57:25.135] GET http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/css/Dashboard.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 7ms]`

Not only that but the URL looks different in the Firefox address bar:  `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/Dashboard\index.html#` < note the backslash and `#` appearing.

I do not have this issue in Chrome or IE10. So it seems that Firefox does not look relative to the path of the html document but rather the server when using an IP address to access, whereas Chrome and IE10 do look relative to the page regardless of using a name or an IP. Firefox also decides to display a backslash and add a `#` at the end.

I have found that coding the links with the folder name does seem to resolve the Firefox IP address issue, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="Dashboard/leaflet/leaflet.css" />` however it messes up Chrome, as the folder name gets added anyway in the network path (seen in the console):  `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/Dashboard/Dashboard/leaflet/leaflet.css`. Why does Firefox behave like this and why  only when an IP is used?

**-Update-**

I have tested this on a colleagues machine and the behaviour is not replicated, frustratingly, so I am starting to think it is something wrong with my Firefox install.

**-Update 2-**

A reinstall and Firefox is behaving as expected with localhost, servername and IP access to the webpage. So hopefully this will no longer be an issue! I am still using relative paths, a leading "/" makes it look in the root folder of the server and affects debugging with localhost.

Comment: could you use absolute URLs for the assets? Like `/Dashboard/leaflet/leaflet.css`.

Comment: a leading slash breaks Firefox when running localhost.

Answer (score 0):

With the way you have the code now, it will always be looking for a folder named `leaflet`, etc, inside the current folder (as opposed to the root/base folder). Try changing it to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- css loading -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/leaflet/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/dashboard.css" /> 
    <!-- script loading -->
    <script src="/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dashboard.js"></script>
    <script src="/d3.v3/d3.v3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
```

Comment: The current folder is the folder in which the html page is running, right? In that case "leaflet" is inside the current folder.  If I use the leading slash it breaks it on localhost. [14:20:06.525] GET http://localhost:8888/leaflet/leaflet.css [HTTP/1.0 404 File not found 12ms]

Comment: Think of the leading slash as a shortcut for writing `http://localhost:8888/` but without having to write the `http://localhost:8888` part. i.e. Whatever folder `http://localhost:8888/` points to is `/` and any other folder inside of it is structured like `/folder1/`, `/folder2/`, etc. On the same note, if you're browsing `http://localhost:8888/folder1/file.html` and there's not leading slash (like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/leaflet.css"/>`) then your browser is going to request the file `http://localhost:8888/folder1/leaflet/leaflet.css` instead ("relative" to your location).

Answer (score 0):

A reinstall and Firefox is behaving as expected with localhost, servername and IP access to the webpage. So hopefully this will no longer be an issue! I am still using relative paths, a leading "/" makes it look in the root folder of the server and affects debugging with localhost.